# Overload JFrame setTitle(String) to setTitle(int)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, overloading

My lesson is to change the setTitle method of JFrame, so it allows integer as a parameter. How to do that? I have to overload that method, right? Anything I tried in the setTitle method ends in a stack overflow.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame
{       
    MyFrame()
    {
        super();
        setSize(400, 400); // Standard initial size
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(MyFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    MyFrame(int size)
    {
        this();
        setSize(size, size); 
    }

    public void setTitle(int title)
    {           


    }

}


public class MainClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setTitle(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

methods `setTitle` from [JFrames API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

```
public void setTitle(String title)
Sets the title for this frame to the specified string.
```

then `frame.setTitle("1000");` will be works

Comment: My lesson is to change the standard method of setTitle, so it accepts integer and no more strings.

Comment: @ANW00D That is simply not possible. You could add an extra `setTitle` method, but you cannot avoid that you can still pass a `String`. And besides, that would be one of the most weird reasons for extending `JFrame` that I have ever heard of

Comment: Hm. Maybe I over-interpret the lesson: "Use setTitle(…), so you can write numbers in the title." But what kind of lesson is that? I would never use my custom setTitle and would use the standard method instead.

Comment: @ANW00D : What if you simply use `Integer.toString(title)` and pass this as an argument to `setTitle()` method, something like `frame.setTitle(Integer.toString(title))`. Won't that do the same thingy ?

Comment: @ANW00D this not possible in pure Java, Java containers came from Native OS, in the form and methods implemented in Java APIs

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track with respect to overloading the method.  Try:

```
public void setTitle(int title)
{           
    super.setTitle(""+title);
}
```

I didn't see a requirement to restrict the original String parameter; this is just adding another overloaded method to your subclass.

**Note:** Agree with Robin that this is a somewhat strange and contrived example...  since normally a title is a String, so why change it...

Comment: Yeah! I don't know what it should teach me. Next week I know hopefully more.